# how populate dropdwon jqgrid with button _click editoption

Tags: jqgrid

I am using form edit. There are three select boxes in the form. One select box is the country, I have a requirement to bind a jq grid combobox with data on click of a button
iam use this code but i dont fill combo with editoptions dataEvents

```
{"name":"read",
"index":"read",
"width":48,
"resizable":false,
"editable":true,
"edittype":"select",
"editoptions":{
  "value":"0:0;1:1",
  "dataEvents":[{
               "type":"change",
                "fn":function(e){
                     if($(e.target).val() == '0')
                     {
                     // actions here...
                     }
                 }
               }]
 }
```

i want fill Dropdown  with button click

```
   $('#myButton').click(function() {
          // Tell JQGrid to load new data
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iam sloved this problem  this soultion

```
function FillGridCombo(Idcol ,JsonStr,Idgrid) {

    $("#" + Idgrid).setColProp(Idcol, {
        editoptions: {
             value:            
            jQuery.map(JsonStr, function (obj) {
                    result = new Array();
                    var jsonString = $.each(obj.Values, function (key, value) {
                        result[value.Value] = value.Display;
                    });
                    return (result);
            }),
        }
    });
}
```